# how can we avoid enhancing while using datanucleus?

Tags: xml, mapping, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to implement JDO with Datanucleus using xml mapping. I am avoiding annotations because it needs enhancing. Is there a way I can avoid this enhancing step and still use Datanucleus?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be: How can i use auto-enhancing with datanucleus?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you've been reading. [DataNucleus requires you to bytecode enhance your classes full stop](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/enhancer.html#enhancement). It isn't that annotations need enhancing, and XML doesn't .... which is totally wrong. It's a trivial post-compile step. Enhancement is common-place in Java these days, used by Spring, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, Guice, and many other well known software packages. Heck, even Hibernate provides for it (and thats after them branding it "evil" 10 years ago hehe)

Comment: thanks for reply. read that post. anyway want to clarify and make sure I am not missing.